# Does breaking a linked list help Python's garbage collector?

Tags: python, linked-list, garbage-collection

I was wondering whether — when I have the opportunity — I should break up a singly-connected linked list in Python when I don't need it anymore, or if I should not bother myself with it.

List example:

```
class Link:
    def __init__(self, next=None):
        self.next = next


L = Link(Link(Link(Link())))
```

Breaking the links:

```
def break_(link):
    if link is not None:
        break_(link.next)
        link.next = None  # link broken

# application
break_(L)
```

Tree example:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, l=None, r=None):
        self.l = l
        self.r = r

T = \
Node(
    Node(
        Node(), 
        Node()
    ),
    Node(
        Node(), 
        Node()
    ),
)
```

Breaking the links:

```
def break_(node):
    if node is not None:
        break_(node.l)
        break_(node.r)
        node.l = None  # link broken
        node.r = None  # link broken
        
# application
break_(T)
```

Basically, what I wonder is, what is the performance-wise optimal way to write your code in this situation. Is the GC prepared to deal with large linked structures? Doesn't it have to run potentially long DFSes with counters and such to determine which objects can be freed? Isn't it simpler to just break the links and give the GC a bunch of loose objects with zero references anywhere?

I could benchmark this, but I'm looking for an explanation (ideally from Karl), if it's available. Thank you.

Comment: who is Karl and does your app/solution need that extra control over the GC?

Comment: I'd preferably not control the GC at all. I just wonder what is the faster way to get rid of a linked list in Python and why.

Comment: if you don't need control of GC writing your program as is for your use-case will suffice. the GC will get rid of the linked-list when it is no longer needed.

Comment: I suppose you are concerned with CPython? If so, please add the cpython tag. Python itself is a language specification, it doesn't impose anything on GC details.

Comment: Secondly, what do you mean by "break the links"? Can you provide a code example for how to do this? Why do you expect this to be less work than what happens behind the scenes?

Comment: @gold_cy Yeah, I know that the GC will get rid of the linked list for me, I just wonder whether there is an explanation why the GC will get rid of the linked list, still connected, faster or slower than me breaking the list first and then letting GC collect it.

Comment: @a_guest Sorry, I updated my question body. Added breaking procedures. And no, I'm not concerned with CPython, as my question hopefully states, I'm concerned about performance in Python. *"Python itself is a language specification,..."* So, what you're saying is that the question cannot be answered?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan This question can only be answered for a specific *implementation* of Python (e.g. CPython, PyPy, IronPython, Jython, ...). CPython uses reference counting and *immediately* cleans up objects whose reference count reaches `0`. Your `break` code (by the way, `break` is a keyword, so that code won't run) only adds overhead to that (and reverses the order of cleanup).

Comment: @a_guest Oh, I get the implementation part, thanks for clarifying. Also, I fixed the code snippets. Does the code actually add overheat? How does CPython's GC know where to start cleaning up the list? It would somehow have to know that it should start at the root and then follow the links one by one, right? Even though the heap is unstructured. What if the list is an n-ary tree? How can it possibly clear this structure in preorder (as reference count drops to zero), when it needs the adresses to child nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) method to your class to see when the object is about to be cleaned up:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, l=None, r=None):
        self.name = name
        self.l = l
        self.r = r

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'__del__ {self.name}')


T = \
Node('0',
    Node('0L',
        Node('0LL'), 
        Node('0LR'),
    ),
    Node('0R',
        Node('0RL'), 
        Node('0RR'),
    ),
)
del T  # decreases the reference count of T by 1
```

What happens with `del T` is that the reference count of the object referred to by `T` is decreased by 1. In this case, it happens that the reference count reaches 0. CPython knows this because it stores a reference count together with each object. When the reference count of an object reaches 0, the object will be marked for cleanup. This cleanup happens before control is given back to user code. So for the above example, it means the object that `T` originally referred to is immediately cleaned up. This first invokes `__del__` and then the corresponding C-code for cleanup. This in turn goes through the object's instance dict and decreases the reference count for each other object stored there by 1. If another object's reference count reaches 0 in that process, it is also marked for cleanup. Then this procedure repeats until no objects are marked for cleanup and control is given back to the main loop.

This is the output from the example:

```
__del__ 0
__del__ 0L
__del__ 0LL
__del__ 0LR
__del__ 0R
__del__ 0RL
__del__ 0RR
```

As mentioned above, when `0` is cleaned up, all other objects it references have their reference count reduced by 1 (i.e. `0L` and `0R`) and get cleaned up as well if the ref count reaches 0.

If you manually break the links of the list by setting the corresponding instance attribute to `None` this adds additional overhead, as it has to actually modify all of these objects in memory (updating their instance dict). The reference count of the child objects reaching 0 is more of a byproduct here. Also note that the order of cleanup is changed since the `clean` function goes depth first:

```py
def clean(node):
    if node is not None:
        clean(node.l)
        clean(node.r)
        node.l = None  # this updates the object in memory
        node.r = None

clean(T)
```

produces

```
__del__ 0LL
__del__ 0LR
__del__ 0RL
__del__ 0RR
__del__ 0L
__del__ 0R
__del__ 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The findings on my machine yield this: if you implement `__del__` yourself, you slow down GC without clean twice. Without `__del__`, cleaning before calling `del` makes the GC run 3x as faster (for this miniature tree), but the cleaning itself takes 7x more time than standalone GC without clean. So you were definitely right about the overhead, but the part about "just a byproduct" is not correct, because the speedup is not negligible. Anyhow, you've been of great help.